# How to retrieve the row and column information of a button and use this to alter its settings in python

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter, widget

I am creating a game and trying to make it in python and tkinter. I have already completed it in word-based python and want to make it graphical.
I have created a grid of buttons to be used as a grid and these buttons currently have the letter "O" on them to show an empty space. However, what I would like is the button to show text of where a pirate is and then eventually the player and chests. The text cannot be hard coded as the positions are randomly selected.

```
while len(treasure)<chestLimit: 
    currentpos=[0,0]
    T=[random.randrange(boardSize),random.randrange(boardSize)] 
    if T not in treasure or currentpos:    
        treasure.append(T)  
        while len(pirate)<pirateLimit:  
            P=[random.randrange(boardSize),random.randrange(boardSize)]     
            if P not in pirate or treasure or currentpos:
                pirate.append(P)    
boardselectcanv.destroy()
boardcanv=tkinter.Canvas(window, bg="lemonchiffon", highlightcolor="lemonchiffon", highlightbackground="lemonchiffon")
boardcreateloop=0
colnum=0
while colnum != boardSize:
    rownum=0
    while rownum != boardSize:
        btn = tkinter.Button(boardcanv, text="O").grid(row=rownum,column=colnum)
        boardcreateloop+=1
        rownum+=1
    colnum+=1
if btn(row,column) in pirate:
    btn.configure(text="P")
boardcanv.pack()
```

This is the main section of creating the grid and works up until this point:

```
    if btn(row,column) in pirate:
    btn.configure(text="P")
```

So I was wondering if there was a way to get the row and column and see if it is in the list?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can call `.grid_info()` on a button widget to get its grid information.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def showGrid():
    row    = btn.grid_info()['row']      # Row of the button
    column = btn.grid_info()['column']   # grid_info will return dictionary with all grid elements (row, column, ipadx, ipday, sticky, rowspan and columnspan)
    print("Grid position of 'btn': {} {}".format(row, column))

btn = Button(root, text = 'Click me!', command = showGrid)
btn.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks. When I run this I get the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'grid_info'

Comment: You run this example and you get an error ? That's highly unlikely.

Comment: The problem you are getting is because you are typing to call `grid_info` on a NoneType object (None). It's in your code on line: `btn = tkinter.Button(boardcanv, text="O").grid(row=rownum,column=colnum)`. Don't call .grid() on the same line as you are defining the button, first declare it: `btn = tkinter.Button(boardcanv, text="O")` and then place it `btn.grid(row=rownum,column=colnum)`

Comment: Thanks, yes I meant when I implemented it into my own, sorry I didn't make that clear but it's working now. Thanks very much!

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue as your last comment Stevo. Very helpful info for a Python beginner.

Comment: I am doing a very similar example but when the button is created the row doesn't have a hard coded value and is dynamic so I can add multiple rows without hard coding. Is there another way to get the row number of a button on a grid?